# Сломался Отчет ReportViever в С#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, nuget, reportviewer

Случайным образом удалил компонент Nuget:ReportViever появился такой msi файл [image: После удаления появилась такое приложение]

Вместо формы reportviewer появился xml код показанный на скриншоте.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исправленная форма:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким способом можно восстановить "Report.rdlc" из xml кода в визуальную форму?

Comment: В вашем вопросе нет вопроса.

Comment: Исправил, добавив  пример который должен получится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил данный вопрос используя Microsoft RDLC Report Designer в "Управлении расширениями" необходимо было его включить